# Windows Mobile Development Unavailable in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-mobile

OK, everyone knows that Windows Mobile Development has been abandoned by Microsoft's Visual Studio Team when it came to Visual Studio 2010.

Instead, we are supposed to use the [Windows 7 Phone SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402530%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Meanwhile, our manufacturing plant still has hundreds of the older Windows Mobile 5 and 6 handheld devices for scanning packages and transmitting data over our internal wireless network.

So, is there an alternate method of developing under Visual Studio 2010 that would create an application that can be run under one of these older platforms?

Specifically, I'm thinking something web based, like a Silverlight app. To my knowledge, Silverlight does not run on Windows Mobile 5 or 6, but that gets the idea across.

I hate telling my boss at the meetings that Microsoft shafted us and left everyone with hundreds of $1000 bricks.

Comment: your devices are not bricks.  you can still build stuff on them.  You just can't use VS2010 to do so.  Use VS2008.

Comment: But that means the rest of our Enterprise solution (which shares classes) is also limited to VS2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an official way of using VS2010 for older mobile development. Instead, [it's suggested](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/1250f599-af61-410f-bc10-135843066a71) that you stick with VS2008 or VS2005 SE for development.

Comment: +1. But, it just makes things so messy. I've got a enterprise wide application here that has linked classes under one HUGE solution with 10 different project to enable the same "look and feel" across our platform. MS is breaking that by having our non-Mobile development in one project for VS2010 and Mobile development in the older VS2008.

Comment: @jp2code - There was some anger in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/windowsmobiledev/thread/422a51c9-7990-44fa-b3b4-3719ddeab495 Maybe someone has heard of an alternative, but as far as official support goes, it doesn't look too good.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, there is no alternative.  Microsoft has made no announcement one way or the other if there ever will be.

Comment: Hi Chris. Does MS want mobile devices to use web apps or are they just saying, *"We don't care about you or the support you showed to us in the past"*?

Comment: I've argued this with them time and again as high up the food chain as I can and while I've gotten some good lip service, I've seen absolutely no action.  For them I don't know that it's about "caring" but more about business, and ROI.  All efforts, and damned near all expenditures, for device development are being pumped into Phone.  Getting a resource spun off to do non-phone device work would either take a person away from working on Phone or take justification of why a new hire isn't for Phone and it seems that right now their org just isn't up to doing it. I hope that will change in time