# PlatformVerificationTask internal error: "The file exists"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compact-framework

Anyone have any insight as to what this error is, and how to fix/avoid it?

```
Warning 1   An internal error occurred in PlatformVerificationTask. System.IO.IOException: The file exists.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   at System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
   at Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.DeviceTypeResolver.CreateDynamicAssembly(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.DeviceTypeResolver.LoadAssembly(String codebase, Boolean canlock)
   at Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.DeviceTypeResolver..ctor(ICollection references)
   at Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.AsmmetaContext..ctor(String ndpversion, String platformFamily, String platformID, ICollection references)
   at Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks.PlatformVerificationTask.Execute()
```

I have doctored up a project to run the compiler to build .NET CF dlls from within VS2010, according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318388/building-compact-framework-applications-with-vs2010-without-vs2005) ( [Building Compact Framework applications with VS2010 (without VS2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318388/building-compact-framework-applications-with-vs2010-without-vs2005) ) . The build *was working* but now it stopped with this odd error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. By... uh.... *Reading the documentation*.

[The doc page for System.IO.Path.GetTempPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) says

> The GetTempFileName method will raise an IOException if it is used to create more than 65535 files without deleting previous temporary files.
>
> The GetTempFileName method will raise an IOException if no unique temporary file name is available. To resolve this error, delete all unneeded temporary files.

So... I deleted the `tmp????.tmp` files from `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp`, and everything worked again.